# Adding Text to Objects During Zooming

Tags: fabricjs2

I am evaluating fabricjs and wondering if you can dynamically add text to shapes while you are zooming.  So for example while zoomed out, the shapes are too small to show the text but as you zoom and they get to a certain size, the text can be shown.  Or is this part of the base control?  In other words if I add text to an object but it cannot be shown because it is too small it automatically hides?